# ¿Do i need to normalize/transform data in a multinomial (nnet:multinom) model? + Dropping variables by Likehood

Tags: r, multinomial-distribution, multinomial-logit, nnet

So, im working with a dataset with controls and 4 diseases, its indeed a nested model cause they are 2 diseases with 2 level each, but i do not know well how to model it.

The thing is i got over 40 features, most of them as continuous data with ranges 4-7, miRNA expression, but others, like weight, have ranges of 50-130 (kgs); also i do have some factors (0-1) and multiple multilevel factors. **¿Do i need to transform or normalize my data to make a model? Im using nnet:multinom.**

From this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QvnsTXfPenU&t=300s I suspect i dont need to normalize them, but i ask here just in case.

And now that im here, im using **Likehood-ratios p-values** since i dont have too many observations (as seen here http://thestatsgeek.com/2014/02/08/wald-vs-likelihood-ratio-test/). **¿Is this also a correct way of dropping variables that are not significant?**

Thank you for your time.

Also my class are a little bit unbalanced. 70 vs 20-25 for each disease. That will be a problem, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I'm more familiar with working with Logit (Multinomial and Nested) in econometric models.

As for the normalization, the estimated coefficient will change if the variable is rescaled. You can to transformations on the variable if you have reason to believe that the relationship is non-linear.

e.g. for a simple binary Logit

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
P(\mathbf{x}) &= \frac{1}{1 + \exp \{ \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1  + \beta_2 x_2 \} }\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

You could then, for example, us the logarithm of $x_1$ instead.

\begin{equation}
   \begin{aligned}
      P(\mathbf{x}) &= \frac{1}{1 + \exp \{ \beta_0 + \beta_1 \log\{x_1\}  + \beta_2 x_2 \} }\\
   \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

I've been taught to both look at the significance of the parameter itself but also to use the likelihood-ratio test, i.e.

We formulate one model with $ exp\{\beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1\} $ where the variables are a subset of the full model with $\exp \{ \beta_0 +\beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 x_2 \} $

the likelihood ratio $$ -2 \left[ LL_{full} - LL_{sub} \right] \in \chi^2$$ which can tell you whether the inclusion of the variable has a significant impact on the model likelihood.

Testing the validity of models with transformations is a little more involved and requires creating a full model where the model with a transformation and the model without transformations are both subsets.

Comment: No-one had answered in a long time, hopefully this could give a little help at least.